# drastic drop in fps on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, scenekit

I made an iPhone app using Apple's SceneKit. On iPhone 5s the app runs with 60fps with very occasional drops to 40fps (I think that happens when not much is changing in the scene). I tried to run the same app, made absolutely no chnages to the code, on an iPad 3 and the app has a huuuuge lag. fps never go above 16. I was comparing the gpu models of 5s and iPad 3 and they are both A7. Why am I experiencing such drastic drop in fps? Is this a hardware problem and I need to lower the graphical intensity of my app?

Edit: the iPad is 3 years in use iOS9, 5s 7 months and runs iOS8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have different GPUs and CPUs.

The iPad 3 was the first with a retina display which means 4 times display resulution over the iPad2. The Pad was quickly replaced with the iPad 4 wich had a stromger GPU with higher clockspeed. Btw the iPad 3 had aARM-Cortex A9 CPU with 1 Ghz and the iPad 4 came with one of Apples first oen CPUs called Apple Swift running at 1,4 GHz.

As for your scene. Might be best if you create less objects on that device or exclude it from the compability list.

Comment: i always imagined ipads have a masterpiece hardware, made for playing games.

Comment: Not the Ipad 3. Apple ended up with lot complains from customers and even endet up with replacing ipads 3 with 4rd in some cases. They learned from that lesion and avoided to announce the iPad 4 mini to early. Just pointing out - the iPad 3 is not a bad device and in its brief time it was a very decent device - just not for everything.